# Each loop skipping values in array

Tags: ruby, loops, each, nested-loops

I'm trying to solve a simple pig latin problem, but when looping over the array, the loop skips a letter.

In this case it's the letter 'h', and I can't understand why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```rb
def louchebemize(sentence)
  # TODO: implement your louchebem translator
  array_of_words = sentence.split(" ")
  array_of_changed = []
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  random = ["em", "é", "ji", "oc", "ic", "uche", "ès"]
puts array_of_words
  array_of_words.each do |word|
    next if word[0] == 'a'
    next if word.length == 1
    word_array = word.split("")
    p word_array
    word_array.each do |letter|
      if vowels.include?(letter)
        puts "Letter #{letter}"
        word_array.unshift('l')
        word_array << random[rand(0..6)]
        break
      else
        puts "Letter #{letter}"
        word_array.push(letter)
        word_array.delete_at(0)
      end
    end
    index = array_of_words.index(word)
    join_word_array = word_array.join('')
    array_of_words[index] = join_word_array
  end
  sentence = array_of_words.join(" ")

  p sentence
  return sentence

end

louchebemize('chat')
```

Returns this, skipping the 'h' character:

```
chat
["c", "h", "a", "t"]
Letter c
Letter a
"lhatcès"
```

Comment: Try isolating the issue itself from the rest of the code. Remove parts of the code that aren't related to your problem until you have only the part of the code that causes the issue. If then you can't spot the problem, post the question here. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Resolved the problem, the deletion was removing items for the variable used for the loop, causing it to skip